# Images not stacking correctly

Tags: javascript, html

I've been making a simply jellyfish game on a website where you must prevent jellyfish from reaching the top by clicking on them and I've run into a problem I cant figure out. You are able to spawn jellyfish in the game (for now) and they will randomly position themselves across a playing field and they should stack on top of each other as each one has a seperate z-index.  They are randomized by randomizing their left margins (This works fine). However, when I click on a jellyfish to delete it, all the other images jump to the left, as if one part of the jellyfish wasn't allowed to stack at all. Here is the current js method that controls the spawning of a jellyfish. Thank you guys in advance :)

```
var spawnJelly = function(jellyType) {
//57 is the width of the jellyfish picture.
var jelliesSpawnPosition = Math.random()*1000 - 57;
jelliesSpawned++
var newJelly = document.createElement("img");
newJelly.setAttribute('src', "https://www.googledrive.com/host/0B-IaOP2CvHbffk56ZWFrUExfX1ZVNWZ0RmRmYU0tMHVoUHVDZzJ1NzhRV2l0c01kSENnNWc/jelly"+jellyType+".png");
document.getElementById("playingField").appendChild(newJelly);
 newJelly.addEventListener("click", deleteJelly);
 // jelliesSpawned is a global variable
 newJelly.setAttribute('style', 'left: '+jelliesSpawnPosition+'px; z-index: '+jelliesSpawned);
console.log("jellyfish created!");
};
```

Here is the method for deleteJelly:

```
function deleteJelly() {
  this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
  console.log("Jellyfish removed!")
}
```

Here is the link to the current website I am making this jellyfish game on.
http://atestingsite.x10host.com/cgi-bin/jellyfishGameC.html

Comment: Can you attach the code for deleteJelly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using position relative, and that means the images take the physical space and will cause page reflow when you remove them. You should change your positioning to absolute (and set the jelly fish container to position relative per Jan).

Comment: ...and set the jellyfish container to `position:relative` so that they position themselves absolutely within the viewport.